# Codeception+Laravel5: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5, codeception

I have created a fresh Laravel 5 installation with codeception. But i get a database error – without ever using the database?!

What have I missed?

**vendor/bin/codecept run**

```
Trying to try to test (WelcomeCest::tryToTest)... 

  [PDOException]                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

**WelcomeCest.php**

```
<?php
class WelcomeCest
{
    public function _before(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
    }

    public function _after(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function tryToTest(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage('/');
        $I->see('Laravel 5');
    }
}
```

**functional.suite.yml**

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        # add framework module here
        - \Helper\Functional
        - Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.testing
```

**.env.testing**

```
APP_ENV=testing
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:JC1MoDVUEhesAe8ftdJlaia7ijihM1T4ApHPbal4KoM=
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```